# Does wrapping hot towel in neck to get rid of sore throat and cold?

Tags: common-cold, ears-nose-throat-ent, sore-throat

I really interested to know if wrapping a hot towel in neck will help to get rid of sore throat quickly? if yes, then why ?

Answer (score -1):

It will not get rid of it but it will help with the pain.

If you have a fever or there are stuff (exudates) on your tonsils. I would have it checked out to rule out strep.

But mostly likely it is viral and you will need supportive care like tylenol for pain.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Dan. The rules here require supporting evidence for your answers. For a simple answer like this a single link to a reputable site supporting what you say above would suffice.

Comment: Note taken. Sorry I did not know the rules. If it helps any I am an MD.

here is a link: https://www.uptodate.com/contents/symptomatic-treatment-of-acute-pharyngitis-in-adults?source=search_result&search=sore%20throat&selectedTitle=3~150#H261420865

Comment: Unfortunately that link requires a login.

Comment: Hi @Dan I understand where you're coming from, I am too.  This site works a little differently than other sites; citations are given (1) so people can look up more info (2) to demonstrate validity of source, since no one can prove their credentials here.  I love UTD but try to link to something from AAFP AAP etc or Medscape NIH CDC .edu and other resources so others can look at it.  Or I pull out the citation that UTD cites for it.

Comment: Also @Dan it usually only takes 30 seconds or so to find a link to the thing you already know.  Other times a little longer.  Now and then for something less tangible, like "what is the flow in the ER" types of things, I have just had to say "source: clinical experience" or lectures or conversations with colleagues, and then it can be taken with a grain of salt.  Also check our Meta and new MedicalSciences site out: https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/798/medical-sciences-has-been-launched-to-foster-a-community-of-experts-and-we-ant?cb=1

Comment: I think you guys are misunderstanding me. I understand why the rules are there, I am not fight that. I just did not know the rules when I posted.